# php cURL cookie saving empty

Tags: php, curl

I have made a successful connection using cURL, but I trying to download a file and its not working. I know it's the cookie because when I open the downloaded file, it contains an authorized required message. The initial authentication is working though. any thoughts

```
// Create a curl handle to a non-existing location
$ch = curl_init('https://xxxx/');


// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// SET POST PARAMETERS : FORM VALUES FOR EACH FIELD
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user=xxx&password=xxx');

// IMITATE CLASSIC BROWSER'S BEHAVIOUR : HANDLE COOKIES
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');



curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$fp = fopen("status.xml", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);


if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}


curl_close($ch);


fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

`CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` is for reading cookies, `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` is for writing.

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/path/to/cookie.txt');
```

Make sure you have full path for cookie file and it have permission to be written

Comment: Actually I got it to work , but something weird is happening. The downloaded file contains the login page and not the xml file I want to download. What am I doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: if sometimes work and sometimes not, that means its related to that server which you trying to get data. I cant say anything. Analyze it and see what you missing

Comment: If you dont use cookie that you get delete `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` line

Comment: actually im sure its a cookie problem, the connection is ok  , but the cookie is empty .. I also checked if the cookie file exists and is writable, it is

Answer (score 1):

Cookies information just be saved into file after the handle closed, like it said in manual:

> CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => The name of a file to save all internal cookies to when the handle is closed, e.g. after a call to curl_close.

[Manual: curl_setopt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)
Besides, you may need to take this into consideration:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```